# Prevent SweetAlert to be closed on clicking outside the popup window

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I am using **Sweet Alert** for a popup on my product view in an E-commerce Application with two buttons: one for going on cart View and another for reloading the view.

But when a user clicks outside of the popup, the popup window closes automatically.
I've tried following properties to stop it to be closed but nothing works :

```
hideOnOverlayClick: false,
hideOnContentClick: false,
closeClick: false,
helpers: {
    overlay: { closeClick: false } 
}
```

Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: in `window close events` you can check for target event.

Answer (score 100):

If you are using Sweet Alert 2, you can use this configuration

```
allowOutsideClick: false
```

This should work.

Comment: @Channel This does work if you're using sweet alert 2

Comment: @Izzy yes but as specified in the question, he using "Sweet Alert" and not "Sweet Alert 2"

Comment: check Swal version. allowOutsideClick: false For SweetAlert 2, closeOnClickOutside: false for version 1

Comment: Thank you, Its working fine i have added to my project. If you are using Sweet Alert 2 then it will work.

Answer (score 50):

## Regarding Sweet Alert 2 (More effective solution)

Actually all answers here don't cover another way to dismiss the popup. And that's using keyboard. Especially the *ESC* key. In order to prevent that you would want to add two options instead of one.

```js
allowOutsideClick: false,
allowEscapeKey: false,
```

### Quick example:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Do not dismiss!',
  icon: 'warning',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Answer (score 34):

The property you are looking for is closeOnClickOutside:

```
closeOnClickOutside: false
```

Answer (score 19):

For SweetAlert 2:

```
allowOutsideClick: false
```

and **version 3** and **some below version 2**:

```
closeOnClickOutside: false
```

Comment: the `closeOnClickOutside: false` works like charm for  Vue wrapper for Sweet Alert by Antério Vieira (https://github.com/anteriovieira/vue-swal)

Answer (score 5):

Use `backdrop:true` with the `allowOutsideClick: false` as following below. It worked for me.

```
swal({
    backdrop:true,
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    title:'Warning!',
    text:'Do you want to delete records?',
    type:'warning',
    showCancelButton: 0,
    confirmButtonText: 'OK',
}).then(function(e) {
    if (e.value) {
        //do what you want
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set this property:

```
allowOutsideClick: true
```

Answer (score 3):

It is allowOutsideClick: false for example

```
swal({
  title: "View Cart",
  text: "Are you sure?",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton    : true,
  confirmButtonColor  : "#ff0000",
  confirmButtonText   : "Yes",
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  CancelButtonText    : "No"
            },
                function() //confirm
            {
                //if Yes do this
            }
);
```

Comment: this didn't work on new version (2.0+) of sweetalert . Although answer given by @Channel worked
closeOnClickOutside: false

Comment: @Irfan Raza The difference in this approach is, if user click outside the dialog, it will confirm the user first, if he/she want to close it or not. Otherwise option in swal allowOutsideClick   : false, is enough.

Answer (score 3):

If the answers above do not work for you try:

`closeOnClickOutside: false`

Answer (score 3):

We are using **higher version than 2** for Sweat alert and in our case we needed.

for Chrome:

```
closeOnClickOutside: false
```

for Firefox:

```
allowOutsideClick: false
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and here's how I solved it: setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

```
var dialog = SweetAlertDialog(context, SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
dialog.setTitleText(getString(R.string.session_expired));
dialog.setConfirmClickListener { sDialog ->
    sDialog.dismissWithAnimation()
    Utils.signOut(context!!)
    Handler().postDelayed({
    startActivity(getLoginIntent(context!!))
    AcTrans.Builder(context!!).performFade()
    }, 500)};
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

### For sweetalert version < 2

```
swal(
         "Records will be deleted permanently.",  //title
         "Do you want to delete records?",  //text
         "warning",  //icon
         {
              closeOnClickOutside: false, // prevent close on click anywhere/outside
              buttons: ["No", "Yes"], //with custom label
              dangerMode: true,
         }
    ).then(ok => {
         if (ok) {
              console.log("deleted")
         }
         else {
              console.log("not deleted")
         }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

For latest version it is

```
allowOutsideClick: false
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't want to close dialog on esc or outside click below is working for me.!

```
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You will not be able to recover this details!",
  icon: "warning",
  closeOnClickOutside: false,
  closeOnEsc: false,
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  buttons: [
    'No, cancel it!',
    'Yes, I am sure!'
  ],
  dangerMode: true,
})
```